# AWS MemoryDB: Is there any docker-image that emulates it so as to use it for development purposes on dev-machines?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, redis, amazon-memory-db

I'm new to this AWS managed service so bare with me. Is it possible to run MemoryDB on localdev via some docker-image which offers a trimmed-down version of it and then connect to said docker-image using the official AWS drivers for golang:

```
      https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
```

I haven't seen any resources hinting in this possibility and I find it very worrisome in the sense that if no such docker-image is available then developers will be forced to use the official "live" aws-managed-service of MemoryDB for day-to-day development.

Comment: I don't see one,  but you can probably just use redis for local environments.

Comment: @DanielFarrell The aws-sdk for memorydb is incompatible with redis - at least that's my understanding

Comment: The SDK is for the API.  The API offers a number of things, including setup of the db instances as well as apparently some query ability.  But you can still connect "redis" style: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/getting-startedclusters.connecttonode.html

Comment: @DanielFarrell Thanks for tip. My question is whether the aws-sdk can be used to connect to a redis docker-image running on localdev using the exact same golang code that would be used to connect over to AWS' MemoryDB in the cloud. I'm under the impression that it's not possible but I'd be happy to stand corrected.